# Spark not working: socket not created by this factory

Tags: java, sockets, pyspark, spark-submit

I installed spark on my computer the same way I did on my previous computer. However, when I try to run my code with spark-submit, I get an error I don't understand.

I already searched the internet for solutions, and tried to install different versions of the aws cli, java, py4j.. Not sure what to do now.

The error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/marjolein/PycharmProjects/conversion_attribution/mca-etl/src/jobs/conversion_paths/conversion_paths_snowflake.py", line 710, in <module>
    ConversionPathAggregation().run()
  File "/home/marjolein/PycharmProjects/conversion_attribution/mca-etl/src/jobs/base/job_base.py", line 26, in run
    self.invoke_job(sc=sc)
  File "/home/marjolein/PycharmProjects/conversion_attribution/mca-etl/src/jobs/conversion_paths/conversion_paths_snowflake.py", line 114, in invoke_job
    print(visits_of_converters.collect())
  File "/home/marjolein/spark/spark-2.3.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 814, in collect
  File "/home/marjolein/spark/spark-2.3.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
  File "/home/marjolein/spark/spark-2.3.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
  File "/home/marjolein/spark/spark-2.3.3-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 7 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 7.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 7, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Socket not created by this factory
    at org.apache.http.util.Asserts.check(Asserts.java:34)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.isSecure(SSLSocketFactory.java:435)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:186)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:326)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:610)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:445)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:728)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:489)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:310)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3785)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1191)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1059)
    at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.SnowflakeRDD$$anonfun$compute$1.apply(SnowflakeRDD.scala:115)
    at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.SnowflakeRDD$$anonfun$compute$1.apply(SnowflakeRDD.scala:90)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.SnowflakeRDD.compute(SnowflakeRDD.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.UnionRDD.compute(UnionRDD.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:67)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PairwiseRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1661)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1649)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1648)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1648)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1882)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1831)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1820)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:642)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2034)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2055)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2074)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2099)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:945)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:944)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Socket not created by this factory
    at org.apache.http.util.Asserts.check(Asserts.java:34)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.isSecure(SSLSocketFactory.java:435)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:186)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:326)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:610)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:445)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:728)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:489)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:310)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3785)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1191)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1059)
    at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.SnowflakeRDD$$anonfun$compute$1.apply(SnowflakeRDD.scala:115)
    at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.SnowflakeRDD$$anonfun$compute$1.apply(SnowflakeRDD.scala:90)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.SnowflakeRDD.compute(SnowflakeRDD.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.UnionRDD.compute(UnionRDD.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:67)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PairwiseRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: Can you share your `spark-submit` command ?

Comment: A little bit anonymized:
```spark-submit --conf spark.executor.memoryOverhead=2048 --executor-memory 8G --packages net.snowflake:snowflake-jdbc:3.5.3,net.snowflake:spark-snowflake_2.11:2.3.0 jobs/conversion_paths/conversion_paths_snowflake.py --input-dir database.schema.table --output-dir database.schema.table --client-module path.to.client.module --date-to-process 2019-06-25 --max-visit-interval 365 --local-cluster```

However, it works with my colleague, with the same spark version..